# Pull text following and preceded by two differing delimiters of a variable length string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out what type of `SELECT` I need to write in order to pull a string that starts after a particular character and ends after another character. My data appears as follows:

```
Path
------------------------------------------------------
\1231254-0000001000-14671899.PDF
\74-0000001001-14672073.PDF
\65551-0000001001-14672929.PDF
```

And I need to return the following, the characters after the second dash and before the period.

```
ID
------------------------------------------------------
14671899
14672073
14672929
```

I know I need to use some variation of `LEN` and such, but I'm having a hard time grasping how best to utilize them considering the path lengths can be different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google and learn about the PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING() functions in TSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `PARSENAME(REPLACE())` to do this:

```
 SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(path, '-', '.'), 2) FROM tableName
```

`PARSENAME()` takes a string and splits it by the period characters `.` and returns the token located at the second parameter's position.

Comment: I think you may mean SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(path, '-', '.'), 2) FROM tableName

Comment: Now that's clever.   +1

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly and is way simpler than I would have thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substring` and `charindex` if the format of the column is consistent.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e5568/2)

```
select reverse (
        substring (
                 reverse(path), 
                 charindex('.',reverse(path))+1,
                 charindex('-', reverse(path))- charindex('.',reverse(path))-1
                  )      
               )
from t
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try and use rtrim/ltrim (provided it is always the same length):

```
select (ltrim(rtrim(path, 12),8)..
```

Comment: OP stated the length varies

Comment: The overall length varies, however if the portion that matters doesn't, you can use this.